# What are the differences between stratified tests and covariates?

Tags: statistics, regression, logistic-regression, chi-squared

I am studying the correlation between several human traits. One way is to use a chi-square test, but this is unable to include covariates. I am also using logistical regression to do this, and this makes it possible to include age and race as covariates.

However, I noticed that some tests support stratified data for a chi-square-like test.

Therefore, I am wondering what are the differences between including covariates in logistic regression and a stratified chi-square test?

Comment: they are completely different methods designed to test different hypotheses - what is the specific research question you have?

Comment: This question is more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. Also it would help others help you if you explain in more detail about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to look at the correlation between two diseases in human, while adjusting for age and race.

Comment: What do you mean by "stratified tests"? Also why do you want to use a chi-square test? Logistic regression will give you much more information. By stratified chi-square do you mean Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel test? That still works ona 2x2 matrix. A Conditional logistic regression is used when stratification or matching is present.